# Bootstrap 3 input - 'type' or 'select from dropdown'

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does Bootstrap already provide an input box that also allows selecting from a dropdown?

Like if I want to search for Apple and there are 12 fruits in the list, I could either select Apple from the dropdown (without typing anything), or I could start typing Ap.. and it shows up suggestions from the dropdown automatically.

Does Bootstrap already support such a thing? I didnt find it in the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) though . I know about button dropdowns but looking for a combo of a textbox + dropdown.

If not, I'll probably make up something using Jquery/a-typeahead-library/bootstrap's dropdown, but it would be good to know if it already exists in Bootstrap 3 (or even 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a jQuery plugin called [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) If you use it with [tags](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags) it will allow you to select existing tag or create a new one by typing. It also supports bootstrap theming.

Comment: Beautiful! I was about to configure my existing typeahead library to allow showing a list when the user clicks on the box before typing anything, but select2 seems even better since it has multiple-select-boxes too which is very useful for my use case

Comment: and looks like [Chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) is also popular and active. After looking at both, I think I'll go with select2 since I am using Django and there's a Django plugin for it

Answer (score 0):

Yes bootstrap provides  such kind of dropdown with input option.Below is the documentation 
[Bootstrap input dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns)

But If you want to do some actions for example 
1.Auto complete search.
2.dropdown selection 
then it is easy to do so by using jquery-ui autocomplete you can type or choose data from dropdown list .see the below link

[Jquery ui autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

**You can also transform bootstrap normal dropdown into editable dropdownlist by using this

Comment: Thanks - I was actually looking for a textbox which could serve as a dropdown also if the user is not willing to type (did not mean having both inline)

Comment: i suggested that too